# How can I configure the debugger in VSC on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Currently my launch.json configuration looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/usr/bin/python3",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
    }
  ]
}
```

I've read that it has something to do with the pathing? I'm on ubuntu and I've tried to make the make the path `"/usr/bin/python3"` as you can see. But it's not working. Previously program was set to `"program": "${file}"` and that wasn't working either.

I've scoured the internet looking for a solution but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you set up a breakpoint and run the debugger?

Comment: The default one (with `"program": "${file}"`) seems to work for me. Note, with this configuration, "Python: Current File" literally means that. So you can set a break point someplace but your current file in the editor is the one that is launched to debug with.

Comment: @OneCricketeer a little window pops up at the bottom right with this message "The Python path in your debug configuration is invalid."

Comment: @JonSG I tried that and still getting the above error ^